# Find column of inverted matrix without finding inverted matrix

Tags: matrices

How would I go about finding, say, the third column of an inverted matrix without finding the inverted matrix itself? I can't wrap my head around this, my standard procedure would be to simply calculate the inverted matrix and extract the desired column.

The matrix in question is as follows:
\begin{bmatrix}-2&-7&-9\\2&5&6\\1&3&4\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ e_3\ $ is the third column of the inverse, its entries must satisfy the following system of linear equations:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-2&-7&-9\\2&5&6\\1&3&4\end{bmatrix}e_3=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but wouldn't that still imply that I have to calculate the inverse matrix to find out what the values are? Using matrix multiplication I mean.

Comment: No. You can solve the equations by [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), equivalent to reducing the tableau
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
2&-7&-9&0\\2&5&6&0\\1&3&4&1
\end{array}\right]
$$
to [row-echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form). To find the entire inverse you'd have to reduce the larger tableau
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
2&-7&-9&1&0&0\\2&5&6&0&1&0\\1&3&4&0&0&1
\end{array}\right]
$$
to row-echelon form.